# Headrule not centered over text, how to fix?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, headline

For some reason the headruler I added in my document isn't as long as the `\textwidth`. It doesn't seem to be centered but it could also be that it's asymetrical, and I don't know why?

See the picture and you will see my document in `\showframe` mode and the headruler not stretching as wide as the text box.

To the left the headruler code is also visible.

So, how to fix this?

[image]

PS; The following code example is similar and reproduces the headruler problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt,titlepage,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\sloppy
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \lhead[]{}
    \chead[]{}
    \rhead[]{}

\usepackage[
    cam,
    width=11.1truecm,
    height=15.4truecm,
    center,
    pdflatex,
    ]{crop}

\usepackage{showframe}
\evensidemargin = -10mm
\oddsidemargin = -11mm
\headsep = 5mm
\textheight = 124mm
\textwidth = 75mm
\marginparwidth = 0pt
\footskip = 5mm

\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\renewcommand\headrule{%
\hrulefill%
        \raisebox{0pt}[10pt][10pt]{%
            \quad%
            \decofourleft%
            \decotwo%
            \decofourright%
            \quad}%
        \hrulefill}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable.
There is another theory which states that this has already happened.

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{universe}
\caption{The Universe}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}
``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe'' \citep{adams1995hitchhiker}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your definition starts with a space (and has several other probably unintended spaces). Try adding a comment at the end of lines that don’t end with control words (lines 65, 67, and 73). Adding a complete example people can compile is helpful too.

Comment: Please -- asusual here -- show us a complete compilable code resulting in your error we can copy and test on our own computers ...

Comment: @TH: Well seen!

Comment: Added some code :)
^^ It's a complex document so started with a screenshot. But yes, a code is a must in order to find problems.

Comment: @VictorEkekrantz: Are you **really** changing layout parameters **and** using `geometry` package together? ;-)

Comment: Hehe yeah I do, @ChristianHupfer. ^^ I learn more and more about LaTeX everytime I use it, I like it a lot apart from the fact it's a bit dated when it comes to Unicode characthers. Especially a problem when it comes to sorting the index xD

But yes, my documents are still a bit patched together x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in your given code are some issues, for example you did not show us the used `*.bib` file, you did not add `\title` and `\author` and you used `geometry` and local settings ...

To solve your issue simple delete/comment the local setings:

```
%\evensidemargin = -10mm % <============================================
%\oddsidemargin = -11mm
%\headsep = 5mm
%\textheight = 124mm
%\textwidth = 75mm
%\marginparwidth = 0pt
%\footskip = 5mm
```

Please read the documentation of package `geometry` (type `texdoc geometry` on your terminal/console) and add with package options the needed margins etc. to `geometry`. I leave this to you ...

With the following corrected code

```
\documentclass[10pt,titlepage,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[% 
  a6paper,
  showframe % <=========================================================
]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\sloppy
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \lhead[]{}
    \chead[]{}
    \rhead[]{}

\usepackage[%
  cam,
  width=11.1truecm,
  height=15.4truecm,
  center,
  pdflatex,
]{crop}

%\evensidemargin = -10mm % <============================================
%\oddsidemargin = -11mm
%\headsep = 5mm
%\textheight = 124mm
%\textwidth = 75mm
%\marginparwidth = 0pt
%\footskip = 5mm

\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\renewcommand\headrule{%
\hrulefill%
\raisebox{0pt}[10pt][10pt]{%
  \quad%
  \decofourleft%
  \decotwo%
  \decofourright%
  \quad}%
\hrulefill}


\begin{document}

\title{test}
\author{test}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly 
what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear 
and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable.
There is another theory which states that this has already happened.

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\caption{The Universe}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}
``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe'' %\citep{adams1995hitchhiker}

%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

you get the resulting pdf:

[image]

BTW: If you use `\citep` in your code you should call package `natbib` ... I also used option `showframe` of package `geometry`  instead package `showframe` ...

Comment: Wow, nice thanks very much appreciated :) ^^ The showframe in Geometry I found especially neat. I will accept your answer because it was very helpful and will sort out the problem for any future visitor to this thread.